# Vite: localhost works fine, but localhost/index.html is blank

Tags: vite

I'm building a basic web app with React and Vite. Everything is in the project folder (`index.html` in the project root, `src/`, etc.) and `npx vite build` puts the compiled project into `dist/`, all as (I think) expected, and the same as a new default React project created from the template.

Starting `npx vite` from the project directory serves the app from `localhost:5173` without a problem. The problem is if I try to load `localhost:5173/index.html` specifically, in which case I get what appears to be an empty HTML page. (There are a couple reasons I'd like to be able to do this.) There are no errors in the console, and just an empty body showing under Elements and Sources.

Trying to load `localhost:5173/index.html` for the new default React project works exactly the same (as just `localhost:5173`), though, even though I can't actually see a difference in any configuration file (or source file, for that matter) between that and my original project.

I'm probably missing something very obvious, but is this obviously a symptom of something I've done wrong?